# Foreign key joining two ktable on streaming database updates

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

We have two database tables which streams updates to kafka topics through a cdc application. We will keep every row's last version on Ktables. Then join them and write to another kafka topic on any update. Our code looks like this:

```
pTable = builder.stream(pTopic, pKeyDbOperationEventConsumed)
                          .selectKey(((key, value) -> key.getId()))
                          .mapValues(pMapFunc)
                          .groupByKey(stringPGrouped)
                          .reduce((aggValue, newValue) -> newValue, pMaterializedAs);
sPTable = builder.stream(sPTopic, keyDbOperationEventConsumed)
                               .selectKey(((key, value) -> key.getPId() + "-" + key.getSId()))
                               .mapValues(spMapFunc)
                               .groupByKey(stringSPGrouped)
                               .reduce((aggValue, newValue) -> newValue, sPMaterializedAs);
sPTable.join(pTable, (sp) -> sp.getPId().toString(), joinerFunc)
                     .toStream()
                     .to(upstreamTopic, producedWithFunc);
```

It worked well with small data on local environment. But we couldn't make it work on production. Our setup is: 5 pods, both topics have 30 partitions. With default configs it started to process, but stuck after processing very small data. We saw **Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing** log. Then we changed configs to:

```
- max.poll.interval.ms = 3600000
- request.timeout.ms = 7200000
- session.timeout.ms = 900000
- num.stream.threads = 6
```

But no luck. It couldn't even process one record. And we encontered this broker log: **Member x in group x has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)**

My first question is if our use case is valid or not. If valid how can we trace the underlying problem?

Comment: Sounds like a network issue. Hard to tell...